# Position FullCalendar events side by side. Limit even size to 10px x 10px

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I was wondering if there was a good way to position `FullCalendar` events as if they are floating left. They would stack vertically after available horizontal space was filled. This would look okay because the events would also be limited to a size of `10px x 10px`.

I understand that I would need to change `left:` and `top:` CSS attributes.

Instead of looking like this:

> ======== ->Event
>   ======== ->Event

It would look like this:

> [--] [--] -> Event     ^  Event

Where could I make the changes in FullCalendar.js?

Answer (score 0):

In `.min` version near `var R,V=la+"-widget-header",ea=la+"-widget-content"` you have the following code:

```
R="<table class='fc-border-separate' style='width:100%' cellspacing='0'><thead><tr>";for(aa=0;aa<F;aa++)R+="<th class='fc- "+V+"'/>";R+="</tr></thead><tbody>";for(aa=0;aa<w;aa++){R+="<tr class='fc-week"+aa+"'>";for(V=0;V<F;V++)R+="<td class='fc- "+ea+" fc-day"+(aa*F+V)+"'><div>"+(I?"<div class='fc-day-number'/>":"")+"<div class='fc-day-content'><div style='position:relative'>&nbsp;</div></div></div></td>";R+="</tr>"}R+="</tbody></table>";
```

Did you try to edit this part.

Worked for me a few months ago.

Comment: I'm sorry what did this accomplish for you exactly?

Comment: old_adam, did you solve this issue? I happen to need side-by-side rendering of events as well.

Comment: Has anyone been able to solve this issue? I am also interested in having events side by side until width of cell is reached and then new line, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the function renderSlotSegs; the code:

```
if (levelI) {
    // indented and thin
    outerWidth = availWidth / (levelI + forward + 1);
}else{
    if (forward) {
        // moderately wide, aligned left still
        outerWidth = ((availWidth / (forward + 1)) - (12/2)) * 2; // 12 is the predicted width of resizer =
    }else{
        // can be entire width, aligned left
        outerWidth = availWidth;
    }
}
```

should be changed to:

```
if (levelI) {
    // indented and thin
    outerWidth = availWidth / (levelI + forward + 1);
}else{
    if (forward) {
        // changed to limit width of first overlapping slot
        outerWidth = availWidth / (forward + 1);
    }else{
        // can be entire width, aligned left
        outerWidth = availWidth;
    }
}
```